# My answer keeps getting suggested edits from spambots

Tags: support, specific-question, answers, spam, deleted-answer

I have been noticing a trend that my [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/425942/103232), always gets edited by some spammer (may be a bot). It's only that answer and no other answer in any of the other SE network.
[Finding subdirectories inside all directories with the same name](https://superuser.com/q/425935/103232)
Why is that?

[image: Timeline for answer indicating repeated suggested edits from spammers]

Additionally, a [replica](https://superuser.com/a/426087/103232) of my above answer is deleted by a Moderator. Both answers are with a difference of 1 minute. I don't remember posting it twice.
Any reason behind that either?

Comment: The deleted extra answer appears to be an accidental double-post. This is rare on Stack Exchange, but it does happen. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: FTR, here's [the timeline of that answer](https://superuser.com/posts/425942/timeline).

Comment: Yeah. That timeline is *very* fishy. (you don't need 10K or even a login to see it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spammers work in mysterious ways - I guess your answer has certain keywords their bots love and it keeps attempting to edit. *Frustratingly enough* - there's not much to do - just let our lovely reviewers reject it (or you can too). There's no tool to protect an answer from bogus edits I can remember (and if I'm wrong, feel free to correct me).

As for the second - its entirely possible you posted it twice. It *is* your account, and the moderator who deleted it is unlikely to remember 6 years after the fact what he was thinking.

Comment: We can lock the answer which would prevent suggested edits. Only problem is that it also blocks comments and votes on it as well.

Comment: @Mokubai - The answer has not received a vote in almost 6 years